# Mongoose Object-literal Subdoc Not Accessible

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

Using Mongoose, how do I access a subdocument in an array? In the schema I have declared my subdocument using an object-literal as per the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#altsyntax).

After I have retrieved the parent document I can log out **doc.children** and see the array of objects, but when I attempt to access any of the documents I get undefined. **doc.children** is not returned as an array, so how do I access the subdocuments?

**Schema:**

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [{ name: 'string' }]
});
```

**Usage:**

```
console.log(doc.children);  //[{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}]
doc.children[0];            //undefined
doc.children['0'];          //undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

The code above looks almost exactly like the documentation here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

I am thinking perhaps there is something else in your code acting strange that you've not displayed here. Perhaps try using get: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get

```
doc.get('children')
```

Comment: Well, doc.get('children')[0].name; works... So is this expected behaviour or should my original code work too?

Comment: Are you using an older version of mongoose or mongo?

Comment: Mongoose 3.8.8 and MongoDB 2.4.9